# can not import scss files into other scss file

Tags: file, import, sass

I am in the process of building a ACL which "angular component library". Idea is to create you angular components few of which will also use ionic features. These components will then be exported to the actual project where we will use them.

Below is the tree structure:
[image: The tree structure]

this **variables.scss** file will have main style sheets, mexins etc.
Challenge that I am facing at the moment is that when I try to import this **variables.scss** file to **tick-tock.component.scss**

It gives me the following error:
[image: The Error]

I have tried

```
@import './variables.scss'
```

also

```
@import '../variables.scss'
```

also this

```
@import 'variables.scss'
```

but its not working.

Comment: Where are you importing it? In the ts file?

Comment: you better read this. http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your tree structure, when importing `variables.scss` into `tick-tock.component.scss`, the correct path should obviously be:

```
@import '../../theme/variables';
```

Comment: even I am still getting the error that 
C:\My-Source\angular-component-library\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:439
  throw assign(new Error(), JSON.parse(result.error));
  ^

Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../theme/variables.